# Installing OpenMDAO 2.6.0 Errors

Tags: openmdao

My system right now is running Python 3.5.2 with pip version 19.0.3 and I'm trying to install OpenMDAO using pip. I run the command like it says on the getting started page of the website to install:

`pip install openmdao`

It begins to runs but then I get the following errors:

> error: can't copy 'openmdao/devtools/xdsm_viewer/XDSMjs/build': doesn't exist or not a regular file

---

Failed building wheel for openmdao"

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to replicate your issue.  Are you starting from a clean environment?

Here is my attempt:

```
 ~ $ conda create -n O35 python=3.5 numpy scipy --quiet
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/swryan/anaconda2/envs/O35

  added / updated specs: 
    - numpy
    - python=3.5
    - scipy


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:            1.0-mkl                
    ca-certificates: 2019.1.23-0            
    certifi:         2018.8.24-py35_1       
    intel-openmp:    2019.1-144             
    libedit:         3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0
    libffi:          3.2.1-hd88cf55_4       
    libgcc-ng:       8.2.0-hdf63c60_1       
    libgfortran-ng:  7.3.0-hdf63c60_0       
    libstdcxx-ng:    8.2.0-hdf63c60_1       
    mkl:             2018.0.3-1             
    mkl_fft:         1.0.6-py35h7dd41cf_0   
    mkl_random:      1.0.1-py35h4414c95_1   
    ncurses:         6.1-he6710b0_1         
    numpy:           1.15.2-py35h1d66e8a_0  
    numpy-base:      1.15.2-py35h81de0dd_0  
    openssl:         1.0.2r-h7b6447c_0      
    pip:             10.0.1-py35_0          
    python:          3.5.6-hc3d631a_0       
    readline:        7.0-h7b6447c_5         
    scipy:           1.1.0-py35hfa4b5c9_1   
    setuptools:      40.2.0-py35_0          
    sqlite:          3.27.2-h7b6447c_0      
    tk:              8.6.8-hbc83047_0       
    wheel:           0.31.1-py35_0          
    xz:              5.2.4-h14c3975_4       
    zlib:            1.2.11-h7b6447c_3      

Proceed ([y]/n)? 

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
 ~ $ conda activate O35
(O35)  ~ $ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
mkl-random 1.0.1 requires cython, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3
(O35)  ~ $ pip install openmdao
Collecting openmdao
Collecting pyparsing (from openmdao)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/0a/001be530836743d8be6c2d85069f46fecf84ac6c18c7f5fb8125ee11d854/pyparsing-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from openmdao)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyDOE2 (from openmdao)
Collecting networkx>=2.0 (from openmdao)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./anaconda2/envs/O35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from openmdao) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda2/envs/O35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from openmdao) (1.15.2)
Collecting decorator>=4.3.0 (from networkx>=2.0->openmdao)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/cd/7c8240007e9716b14679bc217a1baefa4432aa30394f7e2ec40a52b1a708/decorator-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, six, pyDOE2, decorator, networkx, openmdao
Successfully installed decorator-4.3.2 networkx-2.2 openmdao-2.6.0 pyDOE2-1.1.2 pyparsing-2.3.1 six-1.12.0
(O35)  ~ $
```

Comment: I was using Windows subsystem for Linux and my Ubuntu version was 16.04 so I decided to upgrade it to 18.04 before trying again. Trying again it seems to work fine now and I've got OpenMDAO installed. Thanks for the help